# why the Rotation speed of Some Game Objects in Maximize Game Window are faster more than in normal Game window (Maximize is Off) in unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I click play button I start noticing that the rotation speed is a lot faster more than in normal Game window of the a game object . Also the player jump is stronger in maximize view .
Game : 3d
I appreciate your help.
Here is the code :

```
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0.07f, 0);
    }
```

Comment: For the rotation part, have you tried to multiply the rotation speed (here 0.07) by deltaTime ?

Comment: @ThomasFinet no im going to try it  :)

Comment: @ThomasFinet it works fine  now thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code is completely frame-rate dependent! This means if you run at e.g. 60 frames per second you get around `4.2` degrees per second .. but if for some reason you run suddenly with 120 frames per second you rotate twice as fast!

This won't only happen in the editor itself but in particular in a built application which is most probably run on differently strong devices later.

You always want to use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) - the time passed since the last frame - to be sure your values are not in `value per frame` but rather `value per second`

```
transform.Rotate(0, 5f * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

you will want to adjust the value according to your needs of course where `5` now actually means `5 degrees per second` regardless of the frame-rate.

(`Time.deltaTime` is still dependent on the [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html), so in some use cases you even need [`Time.unscaledDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html) which as the name suggests ignores the time scale and uses actual seconds)

---

What happens in your specific case is most probably that in a maximized GameView you can render more frames a second since performance is fully concentrated on the GameView and skipping all the Inspector, SceneView (probably the strongest impact), HierarchyView etc repaint overhead.